# The usage of named and unnamed semaphore

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, semaphore

I've read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788605/named-and-unnamed-posix-semaphores) regarding named and unnamed semaphore , which states that a named semaphore is used for 2 unrelated processes , and unnamed semaphore is used for 2 related processes .

If my program works with both related and unrelated processes , can I use a named semaphore for both cases ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, a named semaphore *always* works.

As stated in the post you linked an unnamed semaphore is easier to handle (because the OS does take care of a lot of stuff automatically) but requires some shared structures between the involved processes.